# Start Spring Boot Application automatically on Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, startup

I made a spring boot application from which I deployed war files. I put it on a Tomcat server. When I click on the Start button it starts fine. I would like it to start automatically when tomcat starts.

How can I do this?

Comment: Spring boot has inbuilt support for the Tomcat container. You do not have to manually deploy your application on Tomcat server as a core Servlet Java application. For what purpose you  deploy your Spring Boot again inside Tomcat Server?

Comment: Please post your codes here.

Comment: It will start automatically war when tomcat starts, can you post your Application class

Comment: When I click on start button application starts. I'd like to resolve this automatically.

Comment: Have you copied the war into the webapps folder? Is the tomcat reconfigured to stop auto deploy?

Answer (score 0):

a) Copy your WAR tomcat/webapps/ folder
b) Navigate to tomcat/bin
c) catalina.bat run (on Windows) Or catalina.sh run (on Unix-based systems)
d) Go to http://localhost:[port]/[context]